# Settings wont launch when performance mode is enabled

Tags: power-management, performance, settings

I'm trying to run my pc in performance mode. however, the option for performance mode is not there in system settings. So when I use `powerprofilesctl set performance`, performance mode is turned on. But if I then try to launch settings, nothing happens. launching it as root from the terminal works, but if I try to see the power options tab, it crashes with the message:

```
**
power-cc-panel:ERROR:../panels/power/cc-power-panel.c:1122:performance_profile_set_active: assertion failed: (button)
Bail out! power-cc-panel:ERROR:../panels/power/cc-power-panel.c:1122:performance_profile_set_active: assertion failed: (button)
Aborted
```

If I then turn off performance mode, settings launch as usual.